# My app is not working after it wakeup from sleep or suspend state

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

My corona app is not working when device go to sleep state. no buttons nothing is responding to continue my game.
I used following code to keep track the system event
. When screen off it prints applicationSuspend but after screen on it never prints the "applicationResume" [Used android adb eclipse to display print messages]

```
 local function onSystemEvent( event )

 if( event.type == "applicationExit" ) then
  print("applicationExit")
    db:close()
  elseif event.type == "applicationSuspend" then

   print("applicationSuspend")
    elseif event.type == "applicationResume" then
      print("applicationResume")
   elseif event.type == "applicationStart" then
  print("applicationStart")
end
end
```

Any Solution?

Comment: Please include the code "around" that if. For example, what function it is in.

Comment: @kikito i included it in main.lua ... no special function is required for that..\

Comment: try using Shane's code exactly. I suspect your problem might be a typo of some kind in one of your ifs.

Comment: @ kikito i used Shane Gadsby's code but the applicationResume never called but all other 3 are working based on the event

Comment: then I don't know what else can you do. Have you tried posting your issue on the Corona SDK forums?

Comment: yes pls see this link..http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/01/20/my-app-not-working-after-it-wakeup-sleep

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure Kikito was pointing out; We probably need to have the function it's inside before we can help more.

as far as I know, this event type can only be used inside a:

```
local function onSystemEvent( event )

   print( "System event name and type: " .. event.name, event.type )
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystemEvent )
```

Styled function.

Is this the way you're using it?